# Is it possible to move a huge WebForms website to MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

It's an entire university website.

Some OLD pages are classic ASP and all of the newer pages are ASP.NET with C# code-behind. We're running ASP.NET 4 right now, so we'd be migrating to MVC 3.

So, some questions;

- How could we go about migrating this website? I've read up a bit and it seems like one can do both MVC and Web Forms at the same time, but how safe is that?
- Folder structure....ours is big. And complicated. How safe is doing the hybrid setup considering our huge setup?
- Is it really worth it? I've been researching and reading up on MVC lately and putting it to use on a personal site, but this would be a huge change.
- Can someone link me to a few examples (with source!) of large MVC projects for reference? I'd love to look at the source.
- How long could this change take?

Comment: Yes, and it depends. You're probably better off creating a new MVC site and gradually moving content from your old site. Running classic ASP, WebForms, and MVC in the same site is theoretically possible, but will add a high level of complexity.

Comment: It is possible, yes.  Just keep in mind, that this may be a mountain not worth climbing, unless you can break it up in to more manageable chunks.  My suggestion to you would be to try migrating something within your existing project that would have the **least amount** of impact and see if it integrates and 'plays well with others'.

Comment: Maybe you should keep your current project running as it is and just handle some parts with the new MVC project. This way, you could move part by part to the new project without messing up your 2 projects. I have failed at this before, trying to keep both types in the same project, and wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will basically amount to a full re-write of the site. Anything less is sugar coating the effort. Even if you re-use all the web pages and use almost none of the functionality of MVC's framework, the regression testing alone would amount to a full project.

It is worth it if you have decided to re-write your application anyways. If you're going to redo it, MVC would be a good way to go, otherwise - I do not envy you.

Comment: Let's say that we really wanted to do this.

Most of the site is a bunch of text, forms, and pictures. Typical university website.

How long would it take to 'convert' each form to an equivalent MVC view? As in, if the original form took an hour to make, should I anticipate the new form taking a lot less time (at least once I get more into it) or should it take the same amount of time?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how we can answer that, as it really depends on how much effort you want to put into it. Do you have to clean up the HTML? Convert it from a table layout site? Do you already have a clean site template set up, or will you have to do that from scratch? How fast are you at writing .NET code? etc.

Comment: Your best bet is to prototype this. Try converting ONE page. Then extrapolate that through your site. Then triple the number you get. That might put you close to the overall effort.

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty vague! Yes, it's possible. Get an application architect to work through the current site and develop a plan to transition it to MVC. I think it's a pretty bad idea to mix methodologies, though. There tend to be rough edges between the boundaries between the two, and if your existing staff is used to webforms, you'll inevitably "leak" webform practices into your MVC site. Commit to the change or don't do it at all.

Is this change worth it? Maybe! Moving away from classic asp is a good choice, so there's a point in favor. Other things that come to mind: What are the pain points for your current site? Is it unstable? Is your classic asp mired in tons of include files? How modular is the site? Do you feel like your staff could train up on MVC? What kind of budget do you have to make the transition? What kind of timeline? If it fails, how much money will your organization lose? How much credibility? What kind of opportunity are you creating for your competitors if you fail?